# Joomla extension update - add column to database table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have read the [Joomla Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Managing_Component_Updates_with_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_4) regarding running SQL files upon extension updates, however the problem being is that the previous version of our extension doesn't have the SQL files therefore this method cannot be used.

I am pretty sure running an SQL command in the installscript.php can be done, so I tried adding the query to the update function like so:

```
function update( $parent ) {

    echo '<p>' . JText::_('MOD_SHOUTBOX_UPDATE') . $this->release . '</p>';

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = "ALTER TABLE #__shoutbox ADD COLUMN user_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'";
    $db->setQuery($sql);
}
```

The query works fine if it's added via PHPMyAdmin and I have also turned on System debugging but the query doesn't appear in the list.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that `update` function is called than the only reason it's not working is you are missing `query` function.

Add this line

```
$result = $db->query();
```

after

```
$db->setQuery($sql);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks Irfan, just noticed that I had forgotten to add `$db->query();` after. Silly mistake.